# TypeError: firestoreService.initializeApp is not a function

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to write a TS script that would take a JSON file and import it into Firebase collection as a document. I am getting inspired by [this tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/firebase-import-json-to-firestore-ed6a4adc2b57) that uses [`firestore-import-export`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-export-import) package. However, even though I have installed the package, I cannot initialize it.
My `scripts/test_import_data.ts` script looks like  this:

```
const firestoreService = require('firestore-export-import');
const serviceAccount = require(__dirname + '/../serviceAccountStaging.json');
const firebaseConfig = require(__dirname + '/../config.js');

async function main() {
  await firestoreService.initializeApp(serviceAccount, firebaseConfig.databaseURL);
}

main()
    .then(() => {
        process.exit(0)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
        process.exit(1)
    })
```

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  "engines": {
    "node": "~v16.14.2",
    "npm": "~8.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "script": "ts-node"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/yargs": "^17.0.10",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "firestore-export-import": "^1.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.7.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "yargs": "^17.4.1"
  }
}
```

In terminal, I am running the script like this with the following error:

```
my@mac % npm run script scripts/test_import_data.ts
TypeError: firestoreService.initializeApp is not a function
        at main (/Users/mymac/projects/my-project/scripts/test_import_data.ts:6:26)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mymac/projects/my-project/scripts/test_import_data.ts:9:1)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
        at Module.m._compile (/Users/mymac/projects/my-project/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1455:23)
        at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
        at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/mymac/projects/my-project/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1458:12)
        at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
        at phase4 (/Users/mymac/projects/my-project/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:567:12)
```

After Google/StackOverflow research, I am lost, now. Have you ever faced similar issue? Do you know what I am doing wrong, please? Any help is appreciated! ♥️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be using an old API for that npm library that was in use before the Firebase SDKs went [modular](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-node-v10). Take a look at the documentation on npm very carefully that you linked to.  The example code looks like this:

```
const { initializeFirebaseApp } = require('firestore-export-import')
initializeFirebaseApp(serviceAccount, appName, options)
```

Notice that the `initializeFirebaseApp` function is a direct import.  There is no "service" object export to call methods on.